# Python serial.readline() does not work in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to read a simple sensor (potentiometer) data from Arduino over a serial port. Everything worked fine when I ran this code:

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

while True:
    try:
        print (str(int(s.readline())))
    except:
        pass
```

I got the output, which changes when I rotate the potentiometer.

Then I tried to make a simple GUI with `Tkinter` (the idea is to have a button, which, when activated, changes a label):

```py
import serial
from tkinter import *

def upd_data():
    try:
        new_value = int(s.readline())
        currentValueLabel.config(text = str(new_value))
    except:
        pass

s = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

root = Tk()

startRecordBtn = Button(root, text = "Read", command = upd_data)

currentValueText = Label(root, text = "Current value: ")
currentValueLabel = Label(root, text = "...")

startRecordBtn.grid(row=0,column=0)


currentValueText.grid(row=1,column=0)
currentValueLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This gives a confusing result. After the label is updated the first time, it stays the same when I rotate a potentiometer and click the button again (does not change).

Arduino sends integer data, the code is very simple:

```cpp
#define inputPin A7

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(analogRead(inputPin));
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me; the value updates when I press the button. Both your Arduino code and your Python code work well. Maybe you have the wrong serial port?

Comment: The port is correct, but it seems that I need to reset it before reading.  I updated my upd_data() as follows:
```
 def upd_data():
    s.reset_input_buffer()
    try:  
        currentValueLabel.config(text = str(int(s.readline())))
    except:
        pass
```
Now I see the values changing according to potentiometer position.

Comment: Interesting that I did not have the same problem. Is your system a Linux, Windows, or Mac?

Comment: @Sam, the port is correct, but it seems that I need to reset it before reading.  I added _s.reset_input_buffer()_ before _try_ block in my _upd_data()_, and I see the values changing according to potentiometer position. But sometimes it shows only a part of a value (i.e. if potentiometer is at position 667, it will show "667', '6', and '7'. I think it will be better to parse serial data rather then just read the line.

Comment: @Sam, it's Windows

Comment: Then maybe what the Arduino considers a newline is different from what Windows considers a newline. To fix this, you could use another character in place of the newline, like `\n`: `Serial.print(analogRead(inputPin)); Serial.print("\n")` in the Arduino code, and the use `s.read_until("\n")` in the Python code. This makes sure that both programs are using the same newline character. You could use any other character as well, or a string of characters: `"thisisn'tanewline"`, if you wanted!